# HTML Canvas (SVG) - Draw image on cylinder surface

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I'm working with HTML5 Canvas now. I have one image file and and a mug image file. I want the image file to be drawn on that cylinder surface. Something like the images below.

[image][image]

Are there any Javascript canvas (or maybe SVG) libraries that can help me archive that?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you found any solution for this? If got pls share it.

Comment: ah, I forgot to add that, I have implemented it by myself and wrote a blog post about it. However, it uses the images from my company's project so right now I publish it. I hope I can make another image quickly, maybe in 1 week I will come back and post the solution

Comment: Thank you for your positive response.

Comment: some typo mistakes in my previous comment, right now I cannot publish it because it uses some images from my company's project

Comment: Ok no need to publish the code. But can you give links or clues about how u achieved it? Or any external library names you used etc.

Comment: I achieve it using purely js, no extra library needed. this should be expressed using some images, hard to tell using words. I will prepare the image and the code and then post it here, maximum 1 week

Comment: actually, I have finished that, but the demo images are taken from my company's project, so if you need that, pm me or send me an email

Comment: Where can I find you email? Pls share it. or contact me at sajith.developer@gmail.com

Comment: I have sent it to you, please check

Comment: any chances to see the code ? :)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve your "wrap" effect by slicing your image into 1px wide vertical slices and changing the "Y" coordinate of each slice to fit the curve of your cup.

Here's example code that uses this technique to "stretch" an image.

Feel free to modify this code to fit along the curve of your cup.

[image]

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/krhQW/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/warp.png";
    function start(){

        var iw=img.width;
        var ih=img.height;
        canvas.width=iw+20;
        canvas.height=ih+20;

        var x1=0;
        var y1=50;
        var x2=iw;
        var y2=0
        var x3=0;
        var y3=ih-50;
        var x4=iw;
        var y4=ih;

        // calc line equations slope & b (m,b)
        var m1=Math.tan( Math.atan2((y2-y1),(x2-x1)) );
        var b1=y2-m1*x2;
        var m2=Math.tan( Math.atan2((y4-y3),(x4-x3)) );
        var b2=y4-m2*x4;

        // draw vertical slices
        for(var X=0;X<iw;X++){
            var yTop=m1*X+b1;
            var yBottom=m2*X+b2;
            ctx.drawImage( img,X,0,1,ih, X,yTop,1,yBottom-yTop );
        }

        // outline
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
        ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
        ctx.lineTo(x4,y4);
        ctx.lineTo(x3,y3);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```